# Extract struct contents in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Say I have a struct such as this:

`flight( bos, nyc, time(  7,30 ) )`

in the form of a variable: `My_Flight`.

If this variable was passed into a function like this:

```
my_func(Flight) :-
   write(Flight[0])
```

How would I be able to extract the contents of the struct and do something with each part like the second line of the above function?

Sorry if my terminology is off, I'm pretty new to this language!

Comment: No, Prolog doesn't have an array syntax like other languages. Prolog doesn't even have *functions*. It has *predicates*. To "extract contents", you do pattern matching. So `my_predicate(Flight) :-
 Flight = flight(From, To, Time), ...`, or even `my_predicate(flight(From, To, Time)) :- ...` Then `From` and `To` and `Time` will have what you want. If you need to break time down further, you can do `Time = time(H,M)` or even, `my_predicate(flight(From, To, time(H, M)) :- ...`.

Comment: Rather than *pattern matching* I really should say, *unification* which is a fundamental behavior in Prolog. It operates through the unification of terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I recommend you think **declaratively**:

*What* must be the properties of such a struct *in order* for `my_func/1` *to hold*?

Answer: For `my_func/1` to hold, first, `Flight` must be of the form

`flight(From, To, Time)`

Using `(=)/2` or, even better, direct **pattern matching**, we can already formulate this as a **constraint** on the argument:

```
my_func(flight(From,To,Time)) :-
    ...
```

You then state what else must *hold* about the arguments for `my_func/1` to hold.

Do not think "how do I extract...", because *the argument may not even be instantiated*. Instead, ask: "What must *hold* about the argument?" This paves the way for many more usage modes: To *extract*, to *construct*, to *check* etc.